# C# Combobox Display Member

Tags: c#, combobox

I am new to c# database programming, and I am designing a simple form that has comboboxes, which are binded and when I navigate thru records the display member of the combobox do not show sometimes and displays instead the value member any idea why it happens. 
This is the code am writing:

```
private void Frm_R_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   #region Form load
   this.land_NewTableAdapter.Fill(reentitiesDataset.Land_New);
   FillCombos("T_Region", id_RegionComboBox);
   FillCombos("T_district", id_DistrictComboBox);
   #endregion
}

private void FillCombos(String TableName, ComboBox ComboName)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format(ConnectionString.DatabaseConnection.GetSQLConnString())))
    {
        try
        {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdCombo = new SqlCommand("FillCombos", conn);
        cmdCombo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdCombo.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TableName;

        SqlDataAdapter DaCombo = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdCombo);
        DataSet DsCombo = new DataSet();
        DaCombo.Fill(DsCombo);

        ComboName.DataSource = DsCombo.Tables[0];
        ComboName.DisplayMember = "Descrp";
        ComboName.ValueMember = "Id";

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

}

And this is the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[FillCombos](@TableName as varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @SQL as varchar(1000)
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Set @SQL = 'Select Id,Descrp  from ' + @TableName + ' order by 2 '
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql
END
```

Structure of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_District]( [Id] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Descrp] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_T_District] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Descrp] ASC )WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Region]( [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Descrp] [varchar](255) NOT NULL, [D2] [varchar](255) NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] –
```

Comment: can you show your stored procedure ?

Comment: i did add it Metehan, thank you in advance

Comment: I think your value member and display member field names is wrong. Can you show me an example table structure which you bind to combobox?

Comment: Structure added too

Comment: I have no idea what's problem of your code. Your table schema and c# code looks okey. What happening when your form loaded?

Comment: When i load the form its displays correctly the valuemembers, once i navigate thru records randomly the combobox would show the valuemember instead of the displaymember.